# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Font not rendering properly

Tags: fonts, brackets, ubuntu-18.04

After installing brackets on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS... i noticed fonts are not rendering properly. I checked for all the font related solution still no luck.

Here is the screenshot what my screen is look like: https://ibb.co/b7393n

And here is the Brackets version : https://ibb.co/ndUow7

Font Settings:

Font : Ubuntu
Font Size : 14

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from a bug in freetype 2.8.1.
The solution I have found is to build the lib from source.

Get it from https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.9.1.tar.gz

Then:

```sh
tar xvfz freetype-2.9.1.tar.gz
cd freetype-2.9.1
sudo apt build-dep libfreetype6
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Then reboot. Problem should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6=2.8-0.2ubuntu2.1
sudo apt-mark hold libfreetype6
```

Type this in the terminal, This helped me, and I had the same problem.